# -Bhidden_def, imported but not exported warnings from linker

Tags: c++, linker, hp-ux, acc

HP-UX' linker complains, when I use `-Bhidden_def`, that `std::` stuff is not exported but it is imported by (my) shared library, e.g.:

```
/usr/ccs/bin/ld: (Warning) Symbol "std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::npos" is not exported but is imported by a shred library
```

Should I be worried and use `-Bhidden` instead?

I am simply trying to hide non-public symbols. `-Bhidden_def` plus `__declspec(dllexport)` simply looks like the closest equivalent of Visual Studio behaviour.